# Phone calls rejected automatically from a specific contact

Tags: bugs, call-screening

I have a Redmi Note 7 phone, from Xiaomi.

Since some time, one specific contact cannot call me directly. Phone calls are automatically dropped and I only get a notification of a lost call. I can call him, but he cannot call me.

I checked and this contact is not in the block list and I tried to remove the phone permission from all apps, but still, the contact cannot call me (so it is not actively blocked by an app).

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

After investigating, using `adb` to read the logs of my phone, I found out that it was an exception which was thrown that would make the call to be rejected.

It is actually a known issue, called Unbind Exception related to dropped calls ([here](https://gitlab.com/LineageOS/issues/android/-/issues/1934) I found info about it).

**How to solve it:**
for people who are not experts, it is almost impossible to find out the cause of the issue. But it is pretty simple to solve it, without having to reset the phone. You just need to delete the contact and create it again. This solved the problem for me.

I thought to share the solution, since I could not find anything about it online. I hope this might be helpful to some!